# Occasionally Connected Application with Flex Air

Tags: apache-flex, air

It is the first time I work with this kind of application. Very little experience I have. And so do the stakeholders. They want something like an (flex AIR)application that is able:

1. save data locally if the application is close
2. synchronize data with the server side if needed

Now, it is time for me to "do something" to this requirement before it get fixed. I have so many questions, but here are some less silly one:

1. The requirement is about "Rarely" connected, not "Occasionally" connected, right?
2. If I can't change the requirement, what should I do, "hibernate" the AIR application like Windows OS or save only the data to local DB? Their possibility ?

Please give me some advice/recommendation.

Thanks,

P/S: Internally, we did discuss about ADEP Data Services features. And I have a sample from Adobe: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/enterpriseplatform/10.0/AEPDeveloperGuide/WS562be5d616a63050-3e6e4f7d131900899a6-8000.html ==> I don't think I have fully understood it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the best choice but we did choose ADEP stuff:

- Data model driven:
  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/lcdses2_mdd_quickstart.html
  --> which help to generate code for both server side DAO and SQLite DAO.
- Adobe synchronization solution : here we create our own lastModified property to compare offline data and server data

If anyone follow our path in the future, pls note 3 things:

- it is commercial, no opensource
- the documentation is good but not STRAIGHTFORWARD
- the samples are good but not STRAIGHTFORWARD

I had to spend 2 days to understand things. And we are now confidence with a fully

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed save data locally in SQLITE on application close and next time the application is launched you can persist changes to server and retrieve updates if needed.

Depending on complexity and data volume of your application, you could:

1. [free] implement the synchronization logic by yourself using only remote
   objects and polling
2. [free] implement messaging on BlazeDS (data push) so the server can push
   updates in real time if needed
3. [expensive] use the all in one Adobe synchronization solution (LiveCycle)

It really depends on what kind of application and data we are talking about.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, we use "Adobe synchronization solution" (dataservices) and lastModified in each object. Thank you, thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can use sharedObject...

```
public var _rememberSo:SharedObject;

_rememberSo = SharedObject.getLocal("loginData");
if (_rememberSo.data.username != undefined && _rememberSo.data.password != undefined)
{
    txtUserName.text = _rememberSo.data.username ; 
    txtPassword.text = _rememberSo.data.password ;
    chkSavePassword.selected = true ;
    btnLogin.setFocus(); 
}
else
{
    txtUserName.text="";
    txtPassword.text="";
    txtUserName.setFocus();
}
```

I have used for locally save the password.. you can use it as per your data...